# Diferença entre "Relacionamento de extensão" e "Ponto de Extensão"

Tags: uml, documentação, diagrama, casos-de-uso

Bom dia!

Qual a diferença entre esses dois termos e o seu uso no diagrama de caso de uso?

Eu já sei o conceito de extensão, porém não entendi a relação entre os dois.

[Relacionamento de Extensão - segundo a IBM](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/pt-br/SS8PJ7_8.5.1/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cextend.html)

[Pontos de Extensão - segundo a IBM](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/pt-br/SS8PJ7_8.5.1/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cextpoints.html)

Se puderem apresentar um exemplo de diagrama apresentando os dois conceitos no mesmo, eu agradeço.

Atenciosamente,

Answer (score 1):

A diferença é o que ponto de extensão define um determinado estado, condição ou pré-requisito para que a extensão aconteça.

Enquanto a extensão acontece quando um caso de uso é concluído, o ponto de extensão acontece em determinada situação (estado, condição, etc).

A figura abaixo (do link http://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-extend.html) ilustra muito bem isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ela indica que, o caso de uso "Get Help On Registration" só ocorre no ponto "Registration Help", ou seja, quando o usuário clicar no link de Help por exemplo. Isso ilustra no diagrama que a extensão ocorre em determinada situação.